# Show and hide div with Window Size JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to show a div based on two or preferably three defined window sizes for mobile.

I'm currently trying to implement:

```
<script>

if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('$div2').hide();
} else {

}

if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('$div2').show();
} else {

}

</script>
```

But it isn't working what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `div2` selector is wrong. It should be a `#` not a `$`.

Also, you should consider using media queries for this!

```
#div2 {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  #div1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #div2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it inside the window.resize http://api.jquery.com/resize/ event

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function{
if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('#div2').hide();
} else {

}

if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
} else {

}
});
</script>
```

And yes the div2 should have # not $