# css @media query + jQuery button to show/hide div when screen gets smaller than a certain width + automatically restore it back when it gets larger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

There are many similar issues overhere, but none of them offer a real solution to what I need.

Here is a jsfiddle demo with small tutorial of the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/V482z/2/ (or full-screen result http://jsfiddle.net/V482z/2/embedded/result/)

As described in the above tutorial, I have succesfully created `jquery` script to show/hide a sidebar content when the screen is smaller, but it is not dynamic. This is a very rare scenario that ordinary user is gonna play with his browser screen size in this way, but none the less, I would like to solve this puzzle.

How to null `jquery` effect of the sidebar div?

Thanks!

for those who do not like jsfiddle and would like to copy this example into a plain html file on your computers, here is the integral code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>jquery show/hide div test</title>

    <style>

      #showhide{
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        display: none;
        height: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #F00;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width:499px) {
        #showhide{
          display: block;
        }
      }

      #container {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #sidebar {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        width: 240px;
        height: 450px;
        background-color: #777;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width:499px) {
        #sidebar {
          display: none;
        }
      }

      #content {
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        height: 450px;
        background-color: #CCC;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="showhide">
      show/hide sidebar
    </div>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="sidebar">#1 automatically show/hide sidebar content when screen IS or GETS resized/smaller then 500px, but leave user the option to show hidden content on demand.
        <br/>
        <br/>tutorial:
        <br/>1. use the JSFIDDLE screen divider line to resize this content and observe the effect when it gets smaller than 500px
        <br/>2. now click on red show/hide sidebar block
        <br/>3. now click again to hide sidebar content
        <br/>4. now resize back the window screen to larger than 500px size.
        <br/>5. Where is the sidebar? Why is it not restored back?
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        #2 content is always visible
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>THE ISSUE:</b> as you can see, when you toggle sidebar in less than 500px screen mode and resize the window back to original larger size, sidebar is still toggled/hidden due jquery effect.
        <br/>
        <br/>
        How to restore jquery hiding of the sidebar div?
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Thanks!
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showhide").click(function () {
          $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, after close examination in Chrome, there appears to exist +18px offset with window size function (css media queries are pixel-precise), so instead at 500px it triggers at 518px for some reason. It is not a major issue, but I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, morning is smarter than night :)

The answer was missing jquery code to actually show/hide divs, and the solution which I found before here [Show and hide div with Window Size JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801813/show-and-hide-div-with-window-size-javascript) was not working for some reason, probably because of my wrong implementation, but also due a bug (should be **function(){** instead of **function{** ).

Here is the missing code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if( $(window).width() > 500 ) {
    $('#sidebar').show();
    $('#showhide').hide();
} else {

}

if( $(window).width() < 499 ) {
    $('#sidebar').hide();
    $('#showhide').show();
} else {

}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V482z/3/